# How to clear my USB memory if it is partitioned on 2 parts?

Tags: partitioning, usb

I am new to ubuntu. I made a bootable usb drive (in ubuntu to reinstall ubuntu). After that,I tried to format usb and it didn't allow me, I tried gparted but it doesn't see usb. So I gave it to my brother and he tried on windows 8, but it showed that it has only 2MB of memory(Empty on windows with free 2Mb,usb had 8GB). When I put it in Ubuntu it show me 2 usb [partitions?], 1 with free2MB, 2nd with Ubuntu on it. What should I do?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and add the terminal output of the `lsblk` command when the USB drive is connected, please?

Comment: Use `dd` to erase the partition table, and then reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gparted, but remember to umount the disk before formatting. To completely "clear" the usb, you could:

1. Insert the USB media in your Ubuntu PC.
2. If it was automatically mounted, unmount it (You can also unmount it from gParted by doing right click on the device, and then unmount).
3. If gParted don't list your device, unmount it externaly, by right click on the desktop USB drive icon, and select unmount volume, or similar.
4. Open `gParted`.
5. At the top right corner you can see the available devices list box. Select the correct one, generally is `/dev/sdb`.
6. Select the device, and delete the partitions. Then apply.
7. Go to the Device menu, and click "create new partition table".
8. Select `msdos`.
9. Create a new partition as `FAT32` (Or what you consider better).
10. Apply changes.
11. When all done, close `gParted`, unplug your USB device, and plug in again to test it.
12. Test it in a Windows computer if you want.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, i tried what you wrote and it worked.                                             
Best regards

Comment: Sometimes it is not easy to unmount ISO9660 partitions using this method, in which case mkusb can be used. I have bricked several multi-partition flash drives trying to format them in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

### Use mkusb and its wipe menu

The main purpose of mkusb is to 'wrap a safety belt around dd', to help you select the correct target drive and avoid overwriting valuable data in other drives.

It uses dd under the hood to wipe the first megabyte (overwrite with zeros), and then, if you wish, it can create a new partition table and file system, (or you can use another tool, for example gparted after mkusb).

The standard for a USB pendrive is an MSDOS partition table and one partition with the FAT32 file system.

See these links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an ISO can change the format of your USB Drive from `FAT32` to `GPT` which means `gparted` won't work on it. The quickest and easiest way is to use `dd` to remove all your partitions making it appear like a brand new empty flash drive.

The first step is to find out your flash drive letter. With it plugged in use:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  69.1G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  58.6G  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 257.4G  0 part /media/rick/ST9_Win7
├─sdb2   8:18   0 200.5G  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   0   7.9G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdc2   8:34   0  58.6G  0 part 
├─sdc3   8:35   0  29.3G  0 part /
└─sdc4   8:36   0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdd      8:48   1  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   1   1.5G  0 part /media/rick/Ubuntu 17.04 amd64
└─sdd2   8:50   1   2.3M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

In this case you see the USB flash drive is `sdd` so you **VERY CAREFULLY** run:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd count=100
```

I cannot stress enough how **CAREFUL YOU MUST BE** because if you typed `sdb` you would loose the 500 GB Hard Drive's partitions (which is painful to fix).

Using the above command, `dd` will fill the first 100 blocks (default block size is 512 bytes) of the USB flash drive with zeros wiping out the MBR (Master Boot Record) which contains the partition table.

Then you can use `gparted` (for legacy systems) or `GPT` (for UEFI systems) and the drive will appear empty and "unallocated".

Comment: GParted works perfectly fine with GPT drives...

Comment: On my `gparted` if I stick a Ubuntu Live ISO planted USB Flash Drive it complains block size is 4096 when it should be 512 and crashes.... or something like that. I could post a new Q&A with screen shots if you like.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a bug, or a problem during creating the live USB, cause mine works perfectly fine.

Comment: It's not a disc... they work ok... it's only USB thumb drives / flash drives / pen drives. Ubuntu ISO's have UEFI embedded with GPT format but I have legacy/CSM boot.

Comment: whoops, I wrote "disc" but meant "drive"

Comment: The optical drive works fine, the USB drive does not. I've seen other comments on the board complaining about the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

In order to format this USB device, you need to use a partition manager to find and delete all the partitions.

Something like Gparted under Linux or Partition Master under Windows are likely your best choices for an operation like this.